# How to implement In-Place Tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

How can I set In-Place Tooltip for my longer text of control just like:
[image]

I have already use this type of Tooltip by using ToolTip.Show Method

```
ToolTip ttpInplace = new ToolTip();
ttpInplace.Show(textbox1.Text, textbox1, 0, 0, 4000);

        private void FormToolPopup_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ttpCustomToolTip != null)
            {
                ttpCustomToolTip.Hide(textBox1);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
            if (s.Width > textBox1.Width)
            {
                ttpCustomToolTip.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox1, -4, 0);//, 5000);
            }
        }
```

But it flickers.
I have read the article from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298402(v=vs.85).aspx
but I have problem to implement because it is in C++.
Any one can help me?

Comment: Interrupts? What does this have to do with interrupts? What do you mean by "using interrupts"?

Comment: I mean sending tooltip messages. Sorry for that.

Comment: What are you using? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: Where exactly you show your tooltip ? If it's in the MouseMove event that could be the source of the flickering... Could you post a longer piece of code ?

Comment: @ digEmAll! I have put previous code. Please review.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid: is your textbox editable ? If so, this way of showing the tooltip is wrong because, as Hans pointed out, you're blocking the editing through the tooltip. Instead, if the textbox is readonly, you should switch to a label.

Comment: @ diEmAll: if I have to use label and text of label is longer than the label rectangle then how can label show all the text?

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid: to use a label, set `AutoEllipsis = true` and `AutoSize = false`. Then decide the size of the label and if the text passes the length of the label, it shows an ellipsis and if the mouse enters the label a tooltip is shown.

Comment: @ diEmAll and @ Hans Passant! Thanks . . .

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid: you're welcome. A side note: you shouldn't put any space between '@' and the name of the user, otherwise no notification is triggered ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it flickers because you display the tooltip at the same location as the mouse.  So the tooltip gets an immediate mouse move message.  Which makes the tip disappear.  Which cause the MouseEnter event to fire again.  Etcetera, flickorama.

One workaround is to capture the mouse so it cannot send a message to the tooltip:

```
   textBox1.Capture = true;
   ttpCustomToolTip.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox1, -4, 0);//, 5000);
```

The capture is automatically canceled when the user clicks the mouse.  Might be good enough, you may have to set it back to false.  Depends.  Best thing to do is implement the MouseMove event and cancel both the tooltip and the capture when you see it moving outside of the control.  You'll also have to do something to make the textbox usable, your tooltip is blocking access.  At least one reason you don't often see this used.  If editing is not intended then be sure to use a Label.  Note its AutoEllipsis property.

Comment: @ Hans Passant! It stopped flickering. Thanks a lot but what is the best way to hide tooltip while leaving from textbox1?

Comment: I explicitly talked about that in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: If textBox1.Capture = true, then all the event have blocked until mouse clicked and there is no way to set textBox1.Capture false.

Comment: No, events are not blocked.  In particular the textbox' MouseMove event will fire.